# Passar objeto para uma proc sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, api

Tem como eu fazer uma SP que receba um objeto? Essa é a minha SP

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_alt_funcionarios]  
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here  
(  
     @id int,
     @nome varchar(60)  
    ,@dataNascimento DateTime  
    ,@cpf bigint 
    ,@cidade  int  
)  
AS  
BEGIN  
    ---- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from  
    SET NOCOUNT ON;  

        -- Insert statements for procedure here  
        update funcionarios set
            nome = @nome
            ,dataNascimento = @dataNascimento
            ,cpf = @cpf
            ,cidade = @cidade
         where 
            id = @id

END
```

e esse é o meu serviço que pega usa essa SP

```
public class PutFuncionario
    {
        BancoContext banco = new BancoContext();

        public HttpResponseMessage updateFuncionario(Funcionario funcionario)
        {
            banco.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec sp_alt_cidade @id, " +
                                             "@nome," +
                                             "@dataNascimento, " +
                                             "@cpf, " +
                                             "@cidade", 
                                             new SqlParameter("@id", funcionario.id), 
                                             new SqlParameter("@nome", funcionario.nome),
                                             new SqlParameter("@dataNascimento", funcionario.dataNascimento),
                                             new SqlParameter("@cpf", funcionario.cpf),
                                             new SqlParameter("@cidade", funcionario.cidade));

            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
```

ao invés de eu passar assim:
funcionario.id,
funcionario.nome
e etc
Passar o objeto inteiro funcionario? É mais elegante e etc

Comment: Não[.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/321338/18246)

Comment: Existe uma forma: você pode serializar o objeto em XML e passar como argumento para uma SP. Veja o artigo: https://www.itworld.com/article/2960645/development/tsql-how-to-use-xml-parameters-in-stored-procedures.html

Comment: Também é possível através do uso de table-valued parameter (TVP). Sugestão de leitura: “Using Table-Valued Parameters in SQL Server” -> http://sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html

Comment: Veja que, um objeto como você diz, é algo que existe numa linguagem, para o banco não faz muito sentido, a não ser que seja um formato padrão, como `xml` ou `json`, mas isso não torna em nada "mais elegante". A procedure foi criada para receber parâmetros e assim funciona muito bem. Passar objetos em linguagens de programação tem outros conceitos envolvidos, objetos pode ser passados por referência, podem ter comportamentos, etc, coisas que não fazem o menor sentido para uma procedure. Apenas apontando que, embora seja possível, com esse número reduzido de parâmetros não faz muito sentido

Answer (score 0):

Pode serializar o objeto e passá-lo para a SP como XML, depois transporta a informação para uma temporária e trabalha com ela:

Precisa alterar ligeiramente a classe `Funcionario`:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlType("funcionario")]
public class Funcionario
{
    [XmlElement("id")]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("nome")]
    public string nome { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("datanascimento")]
    public DateTime dataNascimento { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("cpf")]
    public int cpf { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("cidade")]
    public int cidade { get; set; }
}
```

Depois é necessário serializar o objeto e devolver uma `string` com o **XML** completo e estruturado:

```
private string SerializeXml()
{
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Funcionario));
    Funcionario funcionario = new Funcionario()
    {
        nome = "Joel",
        dataNascimento = new DateTime(1980, 10, 15),
        cidade = 1,
        cpf = 123456778,
        id = 1
    };
    string xml = string.Empty;

    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        using (XmlWriter xmlwriter = XmlWriter.Create(sw))
        {
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlwriter, funcionario);
            xml = sww.ToString();
        }
    }

    xml = $"<Funcionarios>{xml}</Funcionarios>";

    return xml;
}
```

Passar apenas o **XML** para a SP:

```
banco.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec sp_alt_cidade @xml", new SqlParameter("@xml", xml));
```

Por fim tratar a informação na SP e passá-la para uma temporária:

```
DECLARE @intXML INT

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @intXML OUTPUT, @xml

INSERT INTO #TmpFuncionario
SELECT [id], [nome], [datanascimento], [cpf], [cidade] 
FROM OPENXML (@intXML, 'Funcionarios/Funcionario') 
    WITH([id] INT, [nome] VARCHAR(60), [datanascimento] DATETIME, [cpf] BIGINT, [cidade] INT)
```

Não testei o código, mas será algo deste género (pode precisar de algumas afinações).